# What to do if you misplace your ship

Tags: fallen-london

For reasons I'd rather not go into, I recently found myself Unwelcome at the University. Undeterred, I resolved to work my way back in by restoring my academic reputation, and what better place to do so than the Unterzee. 
I acquired a rather dubious vessel, and soon enough I was Embarking on a Voyage of Scientific Discovery!

Unfortunately, after that things get somewhat murky. I emerged from a brandy-induced stupor some time later to find myself on land, with only two-thirds of my notes. Perhaps I burned the rest, perhaps brigands stole them... In any case, returning to Wolfstack shows no sign of my ship moored anywhere.

How can I find my errant ship and crew and continue my scientific endeavours?

Comment: When you go to Wolfstack Docks, what stories are available to you? Is "Put to Zee" there, or "Buying a ship" or "Getting rid of a ship"? Do you have the qualities "Explorer of the Unterzee" or "Acquiring a Ship"? Are there any stories at your Lodgings that could apply, like "Organise your Research"?

Comment: I have no options to put to zee, organise my research or buy/sell a ship, but I do have an option to build a zubmarine. Have I screwed myself by pursuing another vessel before I had finished my explorations? If I now need to complete my zub first it will be a very long time before I restore my reputation :(

Comment: Wrt qualities, I am a zailor in the making 3, embarking on a voyage 3 and acquiring a zubmarine. I am not an explorer of the unterzee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to go to zee unless you have a ship. But you're not required to follow through when you start looking at the shiny plans for a zubmarine – you can back out at any time and start looking for cheaper things like tramp steamers.

So click on the storylet to build a zubmarine, and you'll see an option to back out. Then you'll be allowed to pursue a different zee vessel, and start working towards that instead of the zubmarine. If you just want to go for the tramp steamer, it's nice and cheap. (Frankly, the other ships are incredibly expensive for a fairly small improvement. When you start to run out of things to do and you're building up wealth, then the other ships are more worth it.)